# Receive messages from multiple number using whatsapp php api

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

I am able to send and receive message with use of whatsapp api for PHP, however the API has a simple demo to receive message from a single number only , Can you please help me to make it enable to receive it from multiple numbers specified in list of array or something else ?

I am using a Whatsapp PHP api i.e.
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

and the code to send and receive from single number is.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['running'] = time();
$_SESSION['inbound'] = [];
$_SESSION['outbound'] = [];

$target = '**********'; //conversation target number/JID
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = "<?php echo $target; ?>";
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#message").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13)
            {
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
        Listen(true);
        getMessages();
    });

    function Listen(initial)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "socket.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            timeout: 70000,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                initial: initial,
                target: target
            }
        }).done(function(data) { // on success, you can get the parameter as "data".
            console.log(data) ;
        }).always(function() { //if DONE is used, the service is stopped in case of failure of connection.
            setTimeout(function() {
                Listen(false)
            }, 10000);
        });

    }

    function getMessages()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                method: "pollMessages",
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data)
            {
                if (data.profilepic != "")
                {
                    $("#profilepic").attr("src", data.profilepic);
                }
                for (var i in data.messages)
                {
                    addMessage(data.messages[i], "toMe");
                }
            }
        }).always(function() { //if DONE is used, the service is stopped in case of failure of connection.
            setTimeout(function() {
                getMessages()
            }, 5000);
        });
    }

    function addMessage(message, cssclass)
    {
        $("#conversation").append($("<div></div>").addClass("message").addClass(cssclass).html(message));
    }

    function sendMessage()
    {
        var message = $("#message").val();
        if (message != '')
        {
            addMessage(message, "fromMe");
            $("#message").val("");
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    method: "sendMessage",
                    target: target,
                    message: message
                }});
        }
    }
</script>
```

Which is available at https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/examples/ajaxDemo/index.php

Comment: What did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using single number and its working fine, I don't know much about PHP, so did not dig it much. @bibi